# ng-model is not working in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm setting ng-model in an ng-repeat but only for few radio buttons are initializing with ng-model, i have tried with ng-checked also but not working, i dont know whether the json structure is proper, i am not able to find the issue with this radio buttons. is it a bug with angular js 1.6.4, im using angularjs routing also.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.questions = {
    "fiberQuestions": [{
      "question": "Is CX Installation Crossing Cluster or Sub-Cluster Boundaries",
      "answer": "No",
      "remark": "jkjn",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Not more than 6 downlink cables from one Joint Enclosure",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Is there 90 Deg bending of fiber",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Fiber colour code has been written on CX door",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Is fiber loop arranged properly",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Is Fiber Sagging or low hanging",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "STAR Topology Followed or Not",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Sequential Splicing of all four fibers cores of the 4f fibers in the Joint Enclosure (JE)",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Has Colour to Colour Splicing been done in TBs",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }],
    "cat5Questions": [{
      "question": "Is the CAT 5 properly routed into the customerâs home",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Is CAT 5 crossing power line",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "CAT5 cable is tagged with Customer MQ ID",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Portal Page and its Features",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Speed Test",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }, {
      "question": "Notepad with IDs and Passwords",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "remark": "",
      "questionTemplateType": "1"
    }]
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row cells3" data-ng-repeat="question in questions.fiberQuestions track by $index">
    <div class="cell">
      <label><b><span class="mif-star-full mif-1x fg-red"></span>{{($index+1)+')'+question.question+'?'}}</b></label>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <input type="radio" name="{{'fiber'+$index}}" required="required" value="Yes" ng-click="question.remark=''" data-ng-model="question.answer">
      <input type="radio" name="{{'fiber'+$index}}" required="required" value="No" data-ng-model="question.answer"> </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <h5>Remark</h5>
      <div class="input-control textarea full-size" data-role="input" data-text-auto-resize="true">
        <textarea style="width: 250px;" data-ng-model="question.remark" data-ng-required="question.answer=='No'" data-ng-disabled="question.answer==''||question.answer=='Yes'"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try this `ng-value=question.answer` instead of  `value="yes"` and  `value="No"`

Comment: I just edited your post and the only thing I changed was to place your code in a snippet and nest the fiberQuestions object in $scope.questions which I assume you had done in your actual code.  It seems to run just fine.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: from question 1 to 6 radio button is not mapping with  ng-model. please look at my picture

Comment: @Jacku - did you run the snippet?  Its working there. By the way ... including an image of your output is a bad idea.  Creating a snippet is a better way to go so that we can see the output for ourselves.

Comment: it is working in snippet. Why it is not working in my application?

Comment: @Jacku - I can't answer that.  The only code you gave us to work with has been put in a snippet that is working.  Compare that code to see what is different in your application code.